# How to create Multiple buttons programmatically, get button name whenever press on particular button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, ios6.1

I want to create multiple buttons using MutableArray count. After creating the button, whenever pressing on particular button, I want to display that button name in a label. But Once press on button, it is always showing the MutableArray last index value name. Please help in this problem. I am fresher ti iOS. It's my code.

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad {
    NSMutableArray *Mute_array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", @"Four", @"Five", nil]; 

   for (int k=0; k<[Mute_array count]; k++){
       UIButton *btn_sub_category = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [btn_sub_category addTarget:self action:@selector(clicks:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [btn_sub_category setTitle:[Mute_Sub_Category objectAtIndex:k] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btn_sub_category.frame = CGRectMake(278, k*130, 483, 44);
        [self.view addSubview:btn_sub_category];
    }
}

-(void)clicks:(id)sender{
   label.text=[btn_sub_category  currentTitle];       
   //Here a want to send the name of that clicked button current title
}
```

But, here button current title is always showing MutableArray last object "Five" only. I want pressed button current title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)clicks:(id)sender{
    UIButton *theButton = (UIButton*)sender;
    NSString *theButtonTitle = [theButton titleForState:UIControlStateNormal]
    NSLog(@"theButtonTitle :- %@", theButtonTitle);
    label.text=theButtonTitle;       
   //Here a want to send the name of that clicked button current title
}
```

Try this code.
I using following method to get title of button

> titleForState:
>
> Returns the title associated with the specified state.
>   - (NSString *)titleForState:(UIControlState)state Parameters
>
> state
>
> ```
> The state that uses the title. The possible values are described in UIControlState.
> ```
>
> Return Value
>
> The title for the specified state. If no title has been set for the
>   specific state, this method returns the title associated with the
>   UIControlStateNormal state.

Read Documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/titleForState:

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
-(void) clicks:(id)sender
    {
        if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
            NSString *title = button.currentTitle;

            // do whatever you want with title
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Like,

```
-(void)clicks:(id)sender{
 UIButton *resultebutton= (UIButton*)sender;
   label.text=resultebutton.titleLabel.text; 
}
```